# How do I rebuild my django-mptt tree?

Tags: django, django-mptt

I'm using django-mptt 0.4.2, and want to rebuild a tree.

The tree manager has a method rebuild() which I try to access like this:

```
>>> my_rootnode = MyObj.objects.get(id=12)
>>> my_rootnode.tree.rebuild()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 211, in __get__
    raise AttributeError("Manager isn't accessible via %s instances" % type.__name__)
AttributeError: Manager isn't accessible via MyObj instances
```

I'm obviously doing this wrong. How should I access the rebuild method?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> *AttributeError: Manager isn't accessible via MyObj
>   instances*

`mptt Manager` inherits from `django.db.models.Manager` which can not be accessed via model instances but only via model classes. More infos:[`Retrieving objects`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects)

The model class here is `MyObj`. You are using a model instance `my_rootnode`

the correct usage is:

`MyObj.tree.rebuild()` [(*documentation link*)](http://django-mptt.github.com/django-mptt/mptt.managers.html?highlight=rebuild#mptt.managers.TreeManager.rebuild)

this will build MyObj tree.

Comment: In Django-MPTT 0.9.1 this gives an AttributeError: `AttributeError: type object 'Node' has no attribute 'tree'`. Looks like `MyObj.objects.rebuild()` is the way to go now, though that doesn't seem to work in a migration script because for some reason the Manager isn't a TreeManager then. In the shell all is good. Odd.

Answer (score 23):

work for me:

```
MenuItem.objects.rebuild()
```

Answer (score 7):

Recent MPTT version seem to require the following command. At least it worked for me today, although dash in front indicates that tree manager is private, and probably should not be accessed directly:

```
MyObj._tree_manager.rebuild()
```

Comment: Note that MyObj should be the actual Model Class and not an object. Tested with Django-MPTT 0.8.7 - It rebuilt my broken relations, but there was still an issue with my root categories which were parentless.

Comment: This is correct as of version 0.9 (2022)

Answer (score 4):

manji is indeed right, you need to use the model class to call rebuild.

However, if you want to rebuild the tree only for a specific object and its descendants, you can use :

`MyObj.tree.partial_rebuild(tree_id)`.

Comment: Note that partial_rebuild is not yet part of an official release which is as of today 0.5.5. Thus if you install via pip partial_rebuild will not be available. Anyhow you could use the master branch directly from github. See this: https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/issues/250 ..

Comment: It's now part of 0.6.0 release.