# django-mptt tree rebuild error

Tags: python, django, orm, django-mptt, mptt

I used django-mptt version (0,5,'+dev')

My model looks like:

```
class Comment(MPTTModel):
    content = models.CharField(max_length = 300)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='child')

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['-creation_time']
```

Now, I change Meta in Comment model:

```
class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['creation_time']
```

then, I rebuild the tree under the django shell followed by [**THIS**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541432/how-do-i-rebuild-my-django-mptt-tree):

> models.comment.tree.rebuild()

However, it throws: 
`AttributeError: type object 'Comment' has no attribute 'tree'`

What's wrong with that? How to rebuild the tree in django-mptt?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
Comment.objects.rebuild()
```

Because `rebuild` is a [function defined](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/blob/master/mptt/managers.py#L431) on the `TreeManager class`

In the SO article [you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541432/how-do-i-rebuild-my-django-mptt-tree), I assume he had set a custom manager to the `tree` attribute. But you haven't and thus is on the `objects` attribute.

Are you acquainted with [Model Managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/)?